# Conditional multicast in Rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

There is an infinite stream of messages to Dispatch (implemented as observable). The Dispatch component needs to multicast messages to subscribers (S1, S2, S3, S4).

- subscriber1 should only receive messages of type A, B and C.
- subscriber2 should only receive message of type B
- subscriber3 should only receive message of type C
- subscriber4 should only receive messages of type B and C

I am new to RxJava, what is the recommended pattern for this? Create ConnectableObservable and do the filtering while subscribe? Use Subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`filter()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#filter-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) method to receive only objects you are interested in:

```
PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    
Disposable sub1 = subject
    .filter(it -> it instanceof A || it instanceof B || it instanceof C)
    .subscribe(it -> {
        System.out.println("From A,B or C: "+it);
    });     
Disposable sub2 = subject
        .filter(it -> it instanceof B)
        .subscribe(it -> {
            System.out.println("From only B: "+it);
        });
Disposable sub3 = subject
        .filter(it -> it instanceof C)
        .subscribe(it -> {
            System.out.println("From only C: "+it);
        });
Disposable sub4 = subject
        .filter(it -> it instanceof B || it instanceof C)
        .subscribe(it -> {
            System.out.println("From B or C: "+it);
        });

System.out.println("-- start --");
subject.onNext(new A());
System.out.println("-- 1 --");
subject.onNext(new B());
System.out.println("-- 2 --");
subject.onNext(new C());
System.out.println("-- 3 --");
subject.onNext(new A());
System.out.println("-- 4 --");
subject.onNext(new C());
System.out.println("-- end --");
```

This example code will generate the following example output:

```
-- start --
From A,B or C: testing.A@57fa26b7
-- 1 --
From A,B or C: testing.B@5f8ed237
From only B: testing.B@5f8ed237
From B or C: testing.B@5f8ed237
-- 2 --
From A,B or C: testing.C@2f410acf
From only C: testing.C@2f410acf
From B or C: testing.C@2f410acf
-- 3 --
From A,B or C: testing.A@47089e5f
-- 4 --
From A,B or C: testing.C@4141d797
From only C: testing.C@4141d797
From B or C: testing.C@4141d797
-- end --
```

Comment: I am confused if instead of Subject should I use ConnectableFlowable? I had been reading that Connectable are preferred for multi-cast over subject. Thoughts?

Comment: The `Subject` was just an example of a source. The point is that you can use `filter()` to get only the messages you want.